# Called as a Rest service works great!!! But how to call this method a method in another class?

Tags: java, spring, rest

When I call this as a REST service from Curl it works great!
However, I am now tasked to call this from another method in another class NOT using REST.
How do I do it?
The constructor with the dependency injection is where I am getting stuck - the dependencies don't inject... show up as null.
Was attempting to call like this from an outside class:

```
new SyncRequest().doSomething()
```

```
@Path("/syncMessage")
public class SyncRequest {

    private NotebookService notebookService;

    @ComponentImport
    private final UserManager userManager;

    @ComponentImport
    private final ActiveObjects ao;

    @Inject
    public SyncRequest(NotebookService notebookService, UserManager userManager, ActiveObjects ao) {
        this.notebookService = checkNotNull(notebookService);
        this.userManager = checkNotNull(userManager);
        this.ao = ao;
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Dependency injection will only happen when an object is created by your framework, so `new SyncRequest().doSomething()` is using an object that does not have its dependencies injected. You need to inject `SyncRequest` into whichever component wants to use it to call `doSomething()`.

Comment: I'd also consider separating `SyncRequest` into a class which is a REST endpoint and another which contains the actual business logic, and use the latter class from other components, instead of using the REST component.

Answer (score 1):

From the other class ScheduleJob, in a method I had to inject variables like this:

```
    //Wire these in to call SyncRequest necessary for constructor
    private NotebookService notebookService;

    @ComponentImport
    private final UserManager userManager;

    @ComponentImport
    private final ActiveObjects ao;

    @Inject
    public scheduleJob(@ComponentImport SchedulerService scheduler, NotebookService notebookService, UserManager userManager, ActiveObjects ao) {
        super();
        this.notebookService = checkNotNull(notebookService);
        this.userManager = checkNotNull(userManager);
        this.ao = ao;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }
```

Then in a method call the other class method like this:

```
String response =  new SyncRequest(notebookService, userManager, 
ao).doSomething();
```